# How to reset Observable.interval

Tags: rxjs

How can I construct an observable which emits at some predetermined interval, but also can be made to emit when a second observable emits, at which point the interval will be "reset" to start emitting again at the original interval starting from the point of the second ping?

For example, let's say the interval is 10 minutes. The observable would emit at 10, 20, 30, etc. But let's say the second observable at emits at time 15. Then the overall observable should ping at 10, 15, 25, 35, etc.

Answer (score 11):

In **angular 4** I managed to reset the Interval with the following

```
private ngUnSubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

ngOnDestroy() {
      this.ngUnSubscribe.next();
      this.ngUnSubscribe.complete();
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.pillar_timer_interval =  IntervalObservable.create(3500);
   this.startInterval();
}

startInterval() {
  this.pillar_timer_interval
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnSubscribe)
    .subscribe( ( value ) => {
      //whatever function you calling every 3.5s
    });
}
resetInterval() {
  this.ngUnSubscribe.next();
  this.startInterval(); // start the interval again
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can `switchMap` the first stream under the second.

```
//Outer timer fires once initially and then every 15 minutes
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 15 * 60 * 1000 /*15 minutes*/)
  //Each outer event cancels the previous inner one and starts a new one
  .switchMap(outer => Rx.Observable.interval(10 * 60 * 1000 /*10 minutes*/))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

The result of the above would be an `Observable` that emits every ten minutes but gets reset when the outer `Observable` fires.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. It does what you want, but it's not especially elegant.

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

const resetter = new Rx.Subject();

const resettableInterval = Rx.Observable.of(0)
    .concat(resetter)
    .switchMap((value, index) => {

        let interval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
        if (index > 0) {
            interval = Rx.Observable.of(-1).concat(interval).map((value) => value + 1);
        }
        return interval;
    });

const since = Date.now();
resettableInterval.subscribe(
    (value) => { console.log(`${((Date.now() - since) / 1000).toFixed(1)}: ${value}`); }
);
setTimeout(() => { resetter.next(0); }, 1500);
```

The initial observable contains a single value that kick starts the interval using `switchMap`. The resetter observable is concatenated, so each time it emits the interval is reset. The `index` parameter provided by the `switchMap` operator is used to determine whether or not a initial value for the interval is emitted. (If you don't care about the incremental numbers that are emitted, you can remove the `map` - it's only used to ensure the emitting numbers are reset to zero, etc.)

The output should be:

```
1.0: 0
1.5: 0
2.5: 1
3.5: 2
4.5: 3
5.5: 4
...
```